# Gatling JMS test doesn't seem to terminate

Tags: jms, gatling

In my JMS test, gatling seems to receive the reply message, because it logs:

```
15:52:26.101 [DEBUG] i.g.j.JmsReqReplyAction - Message received ID:1D32A51DC20C42D5E05316A0620A8E4E
15:52:26.101 [TRACE] i.g.j.JmsReqReplyAction - oracle.jms.AQjmsTextMessage@300aed69
```

However the test never seems to terminate and I always get the following console print:

```
================================================================================
2015-08-13 15:54:13                                         110s elapsed
---- JMS test ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0     
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )

================================================================================
```

Am I missing a piece of configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the correlation ID folks.

Comment: I have similar issuer with custom protocol (not JMS) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658603/gatling-stuck-on-submission-of-first-request. Do you you what I might be wrong there?